# React TypeError this.state.data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typeerror

I'm trying to build a OpenWeatherMap App from scratch with react but while accessing the fetched data from the local Testing API I get an error if I try to access nested object inside the json data...Plz help me!

**My code**

```js
const App = ()=> {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{
   fetch('./data.json')
   .then(res=>res.json())
   .then(data=> setData(data))
  }, [])  


    return (
    <div>
      {data.main.temp}
    </div>
    )

}
}
```

**Structure of my JSON file**

```
{"weather": [
    {
      "id": 300,
      "main": "Drizzle",
      "description": "light intensity drizzle",
      "icon": "09d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 280.32,
    "pressure": 1012,
    "humidity": 81,
    "temp_min": 279.15,
    "temp_max": 281.15
  }
}
```

When try to access this property of the file it gives me a typeError of  **Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined** even if map through the **main** property & then try to access it like this ==>

```js
<div>
      {data.main.map(d=>d.temp)}
</div>
```

it gives me an error **Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous, the data will only be available on the next render cycle.

You should test if the data is available before rendering, e.g.

```
{data.main && data.main.temp}
```

Comment: looks like this will also fail, as `main` in `data` is not an array. It's an object

Comment: @thedude you're right but I tried in class based component also I mean componentDidMount but result are still same. So plz tell me the way to accessing the main's temp prop.

Comment: You'll only be able to access it after it's fetched, which takes some time. You'll have to handle this case in your code

Answer (score 0):

Code below works for me, only I have to move data.json to public folder. I tested it locally, created new test project via create-react-app.

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const App = ()=> {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{
   fetch('/data.json')
   .then(res=>res.json())
   .then(data=> setData(data))
  }, [])


  return (
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(data.main)}
      <h1>{data.main && data.main.temp}</h1>
    </div>
  )

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, finally figured it out it was an issue with mounting which is common in React.
**@thedude** was right..Thanks! The final answer is

```js
    <div>
      {data.main && data.main.temp?data.main.temp:''}
    </div>
```

Comment: If @dedude's answer is right, go there and mark his answer was the right one. Don't simply add another answer similar to his.